# Pause MessageListenerContainer to consume new message for specified interval

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Is there a way to pause MessageListenerContainer to consume new message for specified interval?
In our application receiver we are storing incoming events in apache Spark store/cache and executor process events. During heavy load (say 50K messages) we want to pause consuming new messages if processing delay (I.e. all executors are busy). As workaround we have to stop/start MessageListenerContainer, but it gives false impression that Listener got disconnected due to system failure/exception or programmatic due to processing delay.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature in the framework, only `stop()` and `start()`.

You could simply block the listener threads (e.g. with a `CountDownLatch`) when the condition arises.